# Adding depth to wall to fit 54x36" shower pan

Tags: walls, shower

I need to add 2 1/4" to an existing wall depth to fit a pre-built shower pan.
What's the best/recommended solution?

[image]

Comment: please add specification / picture / link to the shower pan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you need to build out one wall because the pan is short 2.25" along one wall.
I would rip a PT 2x4 to 2.25 inches for a bottom plate. Then sister in new studs along the original studs with a 1.25 overlap.  Add your 2.25 top plate and the wall is 2.25' thicker.

If the wall sheathing does not overlap the pan but go behind it reduce the top and bottom plates by .5" and sister the studs the same amount deeper.

Comment: I agree.  Depending on what the OP means by "depth" either the back wall or the left wall look suitable for sistering studs.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I was thinking about doing it to the right (wet) wall but sistering studs with an overlap makes a ton of sense. Will be using your method on the left wall instead.